# Presenting avplayer horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

Is there any way to allow landscape mode in only one view controller in an app? I'm presenting it modally like so:

```
let recViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
recViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .CoverVertical
recViewController.player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: currentScores[selectedButtonIndexPath.row].recapAvailable))
recViewController.player.play()

self.view.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(recViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I know I can manually override each view controller to only allow for vertical orientation (with the exception of the above one) but that seems rather tedious.

Answer (score 0):

***Is there any way to allow landscape mode in only one view controller in an app?***

You have answered the question yourself, see the '[Configuring the View Rotation Settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW47)' in UIViewController class reference. You need to configure your app to support all of the rotations you want, then override each view controller, and yes it is tedious, but it works :)

> Handling View Rotations
> As of iOS 8, all rotation-related methods are
> deprecated. Instead, rotations are treated as a change in the size of
> the view controller’s view and are therefore reported using the
> viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: method. When the
> interface orientation changes, UIKit calls this method on the window’s
> root view controller. That view controller then notifies its child
> view controllers, propagating the message throughout the view
> controller hierarchy.
>
> In iOS 6 and iOS 7, your app supports the interface orientations
> defined in your app’s Info.plist file. A view controller can override
> the supportedInterfaceOrientations method to limit the list of
> supported orientations. Typically, the system calls this method only
> on the root view controller of the window or a view controller
> presented to fill the entire screen; child view controllers use the
> portion of the window provided for them by their parent view
> controller and no longer participate directly in decisions about what
> rotations are supported. The intersection of the app's orientation
> mask and the view controller's orientation mask is used to determine
> which orientations a view controller can be rotated into.
>
> You can override the preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation for
> a view controller that is intended to be presented full screen in a
> specific orientation.
>
> When a rotation occurs for a visible view controller, the
> willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:,
> willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:, and
> didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: methods are called during the
> rotation. The viewWillLayoutSubviews method is also called after the
> view is resized and positioned by its parent. If a view controller is
> not visible when an orientation change occurs, then the rotation
> methods are never called. However, the viewWillLayoutSubviews method
> is called when the view becomes visible. Your implementation of this
> method can call the statusBarOrientation method to determine the
> device orientation.

---

EDIT

You can also look at the [UIApplicationDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:), it has the method

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
```

From the documentation:

> **Discussion**
>
> This method returns the total set of interface orientations
> supported by the app. When determining whether to rotate a particular
> view controller, the orientations returned by this method are
> intersected with the orientations supported by the root view
> controller or topmost presented view controller. The app and view
> controller must agree before the rotation is allowed.
>
> If you do not implement this method, the app uses the values in the
> UIInterfaceOrientation key of the app’s Info.plist as the default
> interface orientations.

---